# totally ordered group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose a no trivial totally ordered group .This group has maximum element?

A totally ordered group is a totally ordered structure (G,∘,≤) such that (G,∘) is a group.I couldnt find a more  exact definition

Comment: Does $(\mathbb Z,{+},{\le})$ satisfy your assumption? That certainly doesn't have a maximal element. (But it looks strange that your assumption doesn't relate the order to the group operation at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the ordering to be compatible with the group operation, such that if $a \geq b$ and $c\geq d$ then $ac\geq bd$.

In this case, the group cannot have a maximal element, which we can see as follows: Assume $g$ is such a maximal element and let $h\in G$ with $h\geq 1$.

Now we have that $g\geq g$ and $h\geq 1$ so $gh\geq g$ which by maximality would mean $gh = g$ so $h = 1$.

But if $G$ is not trivial, it has an element $h$ with $h\geq 1$ and $h\neq 1$, which gives us our contradiction.

Comment: Yes Tobias Kildetoft i agree with your observation . Thanks again to all the help! :)

Comment: @art: If you found Tobias’s answer useful, you should accept it; for information on why and how to accept answers, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).